# Static Port Assignment in SQL Server 2008 Does not save

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ports, multiple-instances

I have two named instances of SQL Server 2008 and am trying to set static ports for each instance.  I open the SQL Server Configuration Manager _> expand "SQL Server Network Configuration" -> click the instance I want to change -> and select TCP/IP.

From here any configuration changes that I make are not persisted after I hit OK.  I've tried setting the "TCP Dynamic Ports" option to blank, and setting my desired port # under the "TCP Port" option under the IPALL section but each time when I return to the configuration screen the changes no longer appear.

I've tried bouncing the service and that doesn't help either.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that my account wasn't a local admin on the machine.  I'm a sysadmin on the SQL Server so I assumed it would work.

The frustrating thing is that the interface didn't alert me that i didn't have permissions it simply told me that my changes were saved and proceeded to ignore them.

thanks to all those who answered though!

Answer (score 1):

Did you restart the SQL Server after you made the change?

Answer (score 1):

Are you changing the TCP Port under a specific NIC or under the IPAll section?

You should be doing it under the IPAll (at the very bottom).